# python set manipulation :the simple script does not output right set after unioning or disjoining?

Tags: python, set

```
all_tags   = ['24', '02', '26', '03', '33', '32', '31', '30', '29', '68', '11']
ref_tag    = str('24')
union_tags = set(all_tags) | set(ref_tag)
left_tags  = set(all_tags) - set(ref_tag)
print(union_tags)
print(left_tags)
```

The above is the simple code which I expect elements in union_tags should be the same as those in all_tags. However, the result is 
set

```
(['24', '02', '26', '03', '33', '32', '31', '30', '29', '68', '2', '4', '11'])
```

The union_tags instead contains two extra elements '2' and '4', which I think it is the result splitting the str '24'.
Again, left_tags should exclude element '24'. However, the result still have the '24'.

Please let me know why. I use the python 2.7 as the interpreter.

Comment: `set(ref_tag)` is `{'2', '4'}`

Comment: `set(all_tags).union([ref_tag])`,`set(all_tags).difference([ref_tag])`,  unless you actually have multiple elements or dupes then the set approach is doing you no favours

Answer (score 3):

Set function accept an iterable with hashable items and convert it to a set object, and since strings are iterables when you pass the string `24` to your set function it converts your string to following set:

```
{'2', '4'}
```

And at last the unioin of this set with `all_tags` would contain items `2` and `4`.

If you want to put the `24` in a set as one item you can use `{}` in order to create your expected set:

```
>>> ref_tag = {'24'}
set(['24'])
```

Comment: all_tags, from my understanding, is the list of strings. so why set(all_tags) behave the same way as ref_tag, I mean, the element '34' in all_tags will turn into two separated letter, '3' or '4' after set manipulation? Does the string lose the iterability in list setting?

Comment: @YisongZhen: `all_tags` is a list of strings. `ref_tag` is a string. Use `ref_tag = ['24']` (i.e. a list contaning one string) and you'll get the expected behavior

Comment: @Kasramvd My second question following this topic is the string list ['34','29'],after set manipulation, why not become {'3','4','2','9'}? Lose iterability? I am confused here.

Comment: @YisongZhen Because as I said, when you pass an iterable to `set` it will create a set object from the items of this iterable (which would be hashable) and in this case you are passing a list object which is iterable and its items are strings which are iterable as well but hashable.If you instead passed a list of list you'll get a TypeError because lists are not hashable. Or if you passed a list of tuples you didn't get any error because tuples are hashable objects.

Comment: Am I still in the right track in understanding what @Kasramvd said?

Comment: @ Kasramvd so you mean that the string '23' in the list, for example, ['23'], although iterable, but loses hashability, and so can not be decomposed into {'2','3'}?